# connect and connectAdvance react-redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I was reading about the react-redux `connect` method in the docs and I note something that I don't quite understand, `connect` takes `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`,`mergeProps` and `options` as arguments, then it performs several equalities checks to avoid unnecessary functions calls but it doesn't say anything about the wrapped component until I read about this function `connectAdvance()`.

What is the flow that `connect()` takes and how it reaches `connectAdvance()`?.

Is `connectAdvance()` taking the results of `connect()` and the `props` from the wrappedComponent and returning a new component with the new props?

Thank you in advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In React-Redux v4, `connect()` did the actual work of generating the wrapper component class.  In v5, `connectAdvanced()` does the real work, and `connect()` is a wrapper that calls `connectAdvanced()` with default options for behavior.